# Data Entry for iPad Help Needed

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am searching for a way to take the current text written in a text box and transfer that to a list, and after the list is full, send that list to an e-mail.

To make better sense of this, I'll explain.  I help out at a youth ministry where the kids are required to check-in at the door.  Instead of writing names down on paper, I have been tasked with designing an app so they can just type the name on an iPad.  Once the kid hits "Submit" button, I would like their first and last name (different text boxes, but could conjoin if easier to code) to be added to a never-ending rtf file or something of the sorts.  This rtf file would then be e-mailed to me so I could keep an online roster.

I have all the buttons and fields in place, I just cannot figure out how to code the submit button to handle the function of placing the current text from the linked boxes in a separate file. If it can't be rtf, I don't really care.  Just wanting something I can e-mail back to my Mac to save time.  If anyone knows how to do this, or somehow finds a site that I missed during my continued scouring of the Internet, please let me know your solutions.

Blessings,

Kyle Baity

Comment: Try editing your title so it is more clear. "Xcode Help" doesn't tell the community much about the problem you're facing nor does it entice people to click on it. A clear, targeted title will help you get the best answers as quick as possible.

Comment: Tags are also very important to make sure your question reaches the right audience. Xcode is for questions about Xcode, not about things you are making _with_ Xcode, and copy and paste are meaningless, particularly since your question isn't about copy and paste. You should tag this with ios and cocoa-touch, and change the title as jmort suggests. You can edit your question using the edit link at any time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I changed everything as you said. Now I just have to wait for someone who can answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an NSMutableArray to which you add new name strings as they are submitted, you can then make this into a string list using `componentsSeparatedByString:`. This allows you to sort and count the names easily if you want to add more features later on.

It's not clear how you want the email to be sent, but MFMailComposeViewController would be a good start, using your list string as the message body.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is what I have so far:

-(IBAction)firstrtf{
    UILabel *First = (UILabel*)[_window viewWithTag:20];
    NSMutableArray List = First.text;
}

I cannot seem to figure out NSMutableArray tags. Still searching for that tutorial as well.

Comment: It sounds like you need to read some basic objective-c texts and follow some beginner tutorials. The apple site is a good place to start, or the Stanford course on iTunes U.